# Progress bar using 2 images

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 images in my wpf app. I use first one as the progressbar background and the second one is a foreground. The problem is shown on the image. Is there a way to implement the progressbar appearance I need?

[image]

Comment: change the `Stretch` mode to `None`

Comment: Better show us some sample code how you are trying to implement to get accurate help.